# Extending API in one project fully exposes referenced API but routes clash

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to split a Core 2.1 WebAPI project into two in order that we can expose two different APIs according to circumstances.  Simplified, we have one API and we want all the read-only (GET) requests in one API and the entire set in another (the "admin" API).  Swagger is enabled in the projects.

I duplicated the project, renaming one (namespaces, etc.) and adding both to the same solution, then commented out all the non-GET controller methods in the read-only project and commented out all the GET methods in the admin project.  I then added a reference to the read-only project in the admin project.

Running the read-only project, the swagger page came up fine, just the GETs.  Running the admin project gave a 500 on the swagger page.  Interestingly, during debugging, I found that removing All the controllers from the admin project, the underlying API from the read-only project was completely exposed straight through and appeared fully functional - not something I was expecting and a potential security issue for anyone not expecting it.

However, I then added one controller back and changed it to decend from one of the read-only controllers, over-riding the ancestor contructor, etc. - it still gave a 500.

Base class:

```
namespace InfoFeed.WebAPI.Features.Account
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Handle user account related tasks
    /// </summary>
    [Authorize]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/account")]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger _log;
        protected readonly IMediator _mediator;

        public AccountController(ILogger<AccountController> log,
                                 IMediator mediator)
        {
            _log = log;
            _mediator = mediator;
        }
```

Descendent class:

```
namespace InfoFeedAdmin.WebAPI.Features.Account
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Handle user account related tasks
    /// </summary>
    [Authorize]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/account")]
    public class AccountAdminController 
        : InfoFeed.WebAPI.Features.Account.AccountController
    {
        public AccountAdminController(ILogger<AccountAdminController> log,
                                 IMediator mediator)
            : base(log, mediator)
        {
        }
```

I thought that perhaps the route might be causing a clash so I tried changing that to [Route("api/admin/account")] - this worked as long as there were no clashing method signatures.  However, it means that there are two sets of routes exposed to the same underlying controller methods.

```
POST /api/account/signin
GET /api/account/signout

POST /api/admin/account/signin
GET /api/admin/account/signout
```

Does anyone know how I can hide (perhaps selectively) the routes from the ancestor class so that only the routes I choose to expose from the descendent class are visible/accessible?

Cheers

Comment: Error code 500 is `Internal Server Error` which is very broad to find the solution. Can you please tell that if you are getting any exception or not. If yes then what is the error message.

Comment: Like I said, I got past the 500 issue by changing the routing and ensuring there were no method clashes, it's the exposing of the underlying API routes that I'm trying to address.

Comment: See [`Application Parts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-2.1)...

Comment: @IronGeek Sweet, does just what I need.  If you can please re-post that as an answer, I'll be more than happy to mark it as accepted. 8-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default MVC will search the dependency tree and find controllers (even in other assemblies).
You can use `application parts` to avoid looking for controllers in a particular assembly or location.

If you have an assembly that contains controllers you don't want to be used, remove it from the `ApplicationPartManager`:

```cs
services.AddMvc()
.ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm =>
{
    var dependentLibrary = apm.ApplicationParts
        .FirstOrDefault(part => part.Name == "DependentLibrary");

    if (dependentLibrary != null)
    {
       p.ApplicationParts.Remove(dependentLibrary);
    }
})
```

> Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-2.1